# Difference of SUM while doing multiple group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like below

| `Pid` | `qid` | `count` | `sum` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 13 | 5 | 800 |
| 12 | 13 | 7 | 300 |
| 11 | 14 | 3 | 100 |
| 12 | 14 | 5 | 200 |

I need to get the difference of `sum` while doing `group by` using `pid` and `qid`

Like

```
SELECT
    /* ??? */
FROM
    tbl
GROUP BY
    pid,
    qid
```

| `Id1` | `id2` | `qid` | `difference` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 500 |

Comment: Do not post images. Include a table for your desired output. Please tell us what you've tried and the outcome of your query, also where you stuck. Thank you

Comment: `SELECT SUM(pid) - SUM(qid) as Diff FROM...` ?  The sample data with 500 doesn't let me confirm - can you use proper data that aligns with what you're asking? Cheers

Comment: A qid has only two pids, or it could be more than two?

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT 11 AS id1,
       12 AS id2,
       qid,
       ABS(SUM(CASE pid WHEN 11 THEN value WHEN 12 THEN -value END)) AS diff
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY qid;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (Pid, qid, value) AS
  SELECT 11, 13, 160 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 13,  43 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 13,  42 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 14,  30 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 14,  40 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 14,  40 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Outputs:

| ID1 | ID2 | QID | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 500 |
| 11 | 12 | 14 | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8jfxWiIS)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a difference of `sum` between all pairs of different `pid` per each `qid`. The easiest and most reliable solution in this case would be to use a simple self join, like this:

```
with agg as (
select pid, qid
  , count(*) as cnt
  , sum(?) as sum1
from your_table
group by pid, qid
)
select
 t1.pid as id1
,t2.pid as id2
,abs(t2.sum1-t1.sum1) as diff
from agg t1
     join agg t2
       on t1.qid=t2.qid
       and t1.pid<t2.pid
```

Obviously, we could optimize it if we were sure that you have just 2 different PIDs per each `qid`, but you haven't mention it